# How to package multiple MSI from same Jenkins build pipeline

Tags: jenkins

I have a common code base that I need to deploy to two different web sites. I recently moved the code base to Bit Bucket and I use Jenkins to automate my builds. I want to build two wix scripted MSI packages from the same build output in my Jenkins job. **Is this possible?**

I've tried to create a second bit bucket repo and build the code in the original to create the output needed by wix, but the original repo was not visible to the second repo.

**I'm assuming** that Jenkins script will choke if I merely code the second packaging step.

```groovy
//Build the code
jenkinsBuildAgent = "msbuild"
msbuildSolutionFile = "My_only_solution_file.sln"

//Package & Publish artifacts (1)
artifactName = "My_First_Artifact"
artifactVersion = "1.0.0"
artifactPackageType = ["msi"]
msiGenerationParams = "My_First_Wix_Script.wxs"

//Package & Publish artifacts (2)
artifactName = "My_Second_Artifact"
artifactVersion = "1.0.0"
artifactPackageType = ["msi"]
msiGenerationParams = "My_Second_Wix_Script.wxs"
```

I haven't tried this script, **I'm assuming** it will fail for the multiple assignments to the same variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by wrapping the entire pipeline in a groovy for loop. In the body of the pipeline artifact, I conditionally set the attributes. This worked, and both MSIs were packaged and published.

```
//Package & Publish artifacts
artifactVersion = "1.0.0"
artifactPackageType = ["msi"]
if (i == 0)
{
    artifactName = "My_First_Artifact"
    msiGenerationParams = "My_First_Wix_Script.wxs"

}
else 
{
    artifactName = "My_Second_Artifact"
    msiGenerationParams = "My_Second_Wix_Script.wxs"
}
```